# prepayment vs on credit

Tags: word-usage

This question related to [another one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/403183), in which Flater gave me a very good explanation. But I just come up with another question and I am afraid editing that question will mess it up, so I create this one instead.

I am a programmer developing software systems for attractions, I observed there are two ways for the attractions to do business with travel agents.

1. Need prepayment from travel agents
2. Invoice the travel agents after purchase made

Now I have to develop a system to record the travel agent's account balance.

One of my colleagues suggest to call it "credit management system", so when a travel agent make a prepayment (1), the system "add credits" to the travel agent's account balance, it seems like [what apple called it](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202359). And, suggest to call the maximum prepayment balance "credit limit". Then the system decrease the travel agent's balance for his purchase.

But what about (2)? The attraction need to set a upper bound for how much an travel agent can purchase and owe to the attraction, call this "credit limit" again?

I have the following questions:

1. How to call the "maximum prepayment balance"?
2. How to call the "upper bound for how much an travel agent can owe to the attraction"?
3. When a travel agent make a "deposit" or a "prepayment", should the system recorded it as a "credit"?
4. When a travel agent make a purchase and amount is deducted from the balance, should the system recorded it as a "debit"?

Answer (score 2):

*Credit*, according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/credit) (noun, sense 2), means:

> a :  the balance in a person's favor in an account
>   b :  an amount or sum placed at a person's disposal by a bank
>   c :  **the provision of money, goods, or services with the expectation of future payment**  also :  money, goods, or services so provided
>   d (1) :  an entry on the right-hand side of an account constituting **an addition to a revenue, net worth, or liability account**
>   d (2) :  a deduction from an expense or asset account
>   e :  any one of or the sum of the items entered on the right-hand side of an account
>   f :  a deduction from an amount otherwise due

(I bolded the specific senses that are relevant to your questions.)

I would say:

1. You should not need a term for this, as there should not be any chance that such a limit would be hit; you should be willing to accept as much money as any agent gives you.  (And they have a vested interest in not letting a large balance sit in your accounts instead of their own.)  If you really need a term, "Maximum balance" would be appropriate.  (You don't need to call it a *prepayment balance*, just the word *balance* encompasses the meaning appropriately: "*accounting* :  an amount in excess especially on the credit side of an account" (also from [M-W.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/balance), sense 8c).)
2. *Credit Limit* is the industry standard term for that; referencing sense (c) above, it is the limit of how much monetary value I am willing to give you before you have paid for it.
3. A *credit* to an account is an addition of funds (sense (d(1)) above), so yes, if they send you money, it is a credit.
4. A *debit* is the opposite of a credit, and is the correct term to use when you deduct money from an account.